# perl precedence on glob @argv

Tags: windows, perl, glob, operator-precedence

Since on Windows *.csv doesn't expand from the command line to @ARGV i typically end up doing something like

`map { glob } @ARGV` to get the filenames.

However, I came across an anomally and just wanted to understand what was really going on. I've just finished reading "Stranger in a Strange Land" so i could say I don't fully grok!

```
use Modern::Perl;

# gets the filelist but then warns
say "Test 1 ", '-' x 20;
do { func($_) for map { glob } @ARGV } or warn "at least one arg expected\n";
say '-' x 27, "\n";

# works ok
say "Test 2 ", '-' x 20;
my @x = map { glob } @ARGV or warn "at least one arg expected\n";
func($_) for @x;
say '-' x 27, "\n";

# prints 2 (there are two files)
say "Test 3 ", '-' x 20;
func($_) for (map { glob } @ARGV or warn "at least one arg expected\n");
say '-' x 27, "\n";

sub func { 
  say "in func = $_[0]";
}
```

outputs:

```
Test 1 --------------------
in func = t.csv
in func = t2.csv
at least one arg expected
---------------------------

Test 2 --------------------
in func = t.csv
in func = t2.csv
---------------------------

Test 3 --------------------
in func = 2
---------------------------
```

**Test1:** I don't understand why the `do` doesn't return truefully, `func` returns the last statement which is `say`, which returns true if something was output. Or is it the `for` that is used as the return to `do`?

**Test3:** Obviously a scalar context is implied but how? I used parenthesis around the map?

Thanks,
Richard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Test 1

The first case is evaluating false (which you might think of as being void) because of the `for` statement modifier. Observe:

```
  DB<1> x do { func($_) for map { glob } @ARGV }
in func = t.csv
in func = t2.csv
0  ''
  DB<2> x do { func 't.csv' ; func 't2.csv' }
in func = t.csv
in func = t2.csv
0  1
```

Note that it is a *statement* modifier and not an expression modifier. In languages that make this distinction, expressions have return values but not statements.

Perl is such a language. Given the simple program

```
#! perl
@a = (1 for 6, 7, 8);
```

Attempting to run it fails with a syntax error.

```
syntax error at foo line 2, near "1 for "
Execution of foo aborted due to compilation errors.
```

You might express your intent in the first test more directly

```
map func($_), map glob, @ARGV or warn "at least one arg expected\n";
```

to give the expected output.

```
Test 1 --------------------
in func = t.csv
in func = t2.csv
---------------------------
```

#### Test 3

In the third case, you get scalar context because that’s how [Perl’s logical-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or) is defined to work.

> #### C-style Logical Or
>
> Binary `||` performs a short-circuit logical OR operation. That is, if the left operand is true, the right operand is not even evaluated. Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated.

The left operand is evaluated in binary (scalar) context always. The context of the whole expression is imputed to the right operand only.

Comment: What's puzzling is 'Test 1'. That `map` in void context isn't going to answer why the `do` is evaluating to false.

Comment: @Zaid But it’s not in void context. The logical-or imputes a scalar context and uses the return value from `map` to decide whether to evaluate the right operand. Note that the `for` modifier is the issue. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple, and posting a working, portable solution.

---

#### Test 1

You're checking the result of `do`.

It's the result of the `for`, the last operation evaluated by the `do`, and `for` doesn't return anything useful.

---

#### Test 2

You're checking the result of the list assignment.

List assignment in scalar context evaluates the number of scalars returned by its right-hand side (`map`).

---

#### Test 3

You're iterating over the value returned by the `or`.

The `or` returns either its LHS (which is evaluated in scalar context) or its RHS. That would be the value returned by `map` evaluated in scalar context (a number) or the value returned by `warn` (a boolean).

---

You're hoping the ops return both a list and a number at the same time. That doesn't work.

Note that you want `bsd_glob` or else paths with spaces will get broken. (`glob` actually uses the guts of `bsd_glob`!)

```
use File::Glob qw( bsd_glob );
@ARGV = map bsd_glob($_), @ARGV if $^O eq 'MSWin32';
die if @ARGV < 2;
func($_) for @ARGV;
```